# Como puedo hacer que mi JScrollPane funcione en funcion del contenido nuevo que se agrega, es decir, segun voy agregando paneles el scroll se desplace

Tags: java

> ¿Como puedo hacer que mi JScrollPane funcione en funcion del contenido nuevo que se agrega, es decir, segun voy agregando paneles el scroll se desplace?

```
public class Paneles2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JTextField textField;
private JLabel lblNewLabel;
JPanel panel_1,panel_2;
JScrollPane sp;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Paneles2 frame = new Paneles2();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

> mi constructor

```
public Paneles2() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);         
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 550));          
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```

> creo el panel de la izquierda y añado sus componentes

```
        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        add(panel_1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel_1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        panel_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
        panel_1.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
```

> creo el boton para agregar los paneles

```
        JButton agregar = new JButton("agregar");
        agregar.addActionListener(this);            
        panel_1.add(agregar);
```

> creo el panel de la derecha (el central) y el JScrollPane

```
        panel_2 = new JPanel();             
        sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setViewportView(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel_2.setPreferredSize(panel_2.getPreferredSize());
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
        pack();
    }
```

> funcion para agregar nuevos paneles

```
    private void crearPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Border borde = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        panel.setBorder(borde);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 150));            
        panel_2.add(panel);         
    }
```

> listener sobreesrito del boton

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        crearPanel();
        revalidate();               
}
```

}